# perforce workspace disappear after inactivity

Tags: perforce

for a project I usually create several workspaces on the same host to work on different aspect of the project. However I've find that the workspaces that I stop using for more than a couple weeks disappears(I don't interact with it through command line or GUI). and I'd get a 'clientroot missing' error. The workspace folder is still on my local drive. Is there a limit to how many workspace one can create on 1 host/how long a workspace can stay inactive before being deleted? Is there a way for me to get it back somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't normal behavior for Perforce and my guess is that your admin is running some sort of home-made cleanup script, which is probably unnecessary or at the very least overzealous (unless you're using the free version and limited on how many workspaces you can create, in which case I'd suggest changing your workflow to not burn so much of a limited resource).

If that is the case, you'll need to talk to your admin about exactly what the rules are and whether the workspaces are being archived in any way before they're purged.

Comment: Example of such a cleanup script: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/scripts/pd_cleanup.pl